# How to set action bar event of setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) for two different parent activities

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar

I have the flow of activities in two different ways..

Flow 1:
   act 1 -> act 2 -> act 4-> act 5-> act 6...
Flow 2:
   act 1-> act 2-> act 3-> act 4-> act 5-> act 6...

From this, how to set Parent activity for act 4 to set setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled for action bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in these type of apps.

The only way is to check the user pressing back button

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    super.onBackPressed()
}
```

then send him to selected activity based on condition(situation).

Comment: Yes Mr. Kashif. I used back pressed, it works fine. But my question is, is this possible to do with action bar UpEnabled option... Because we notified only one parent activity name in manifest file. So how the another one flow identifies to go previous one?

Comment: I suggest you use Fragments for this situation.